# Creating Update button and Cancel button using button group and then to add ( | ) between two buttons

Tags: html, css

I want to show two buttons as update button and cancel button like one button from user view.And then, I want to add (|) between two buttons.I added `<span>` tag to show | between two buttons. And then, I created two buttons for the update and delete.I tried a lot of time But I can't do that.How can I do that?Please help me.

```css
.footer-button1{
     background-color: #85b59d;
           width: 60px;
           margin-top: 10px;
           display: inline-block;
           text-align: center;
           height: 30px;
           border-radius: 5px;
           border: none;
           margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
         <button type="button" class="btn footer-button1">Update</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn footer-button1"> <span style="margin-left: -10px;">|</span> Delete</button>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Remove margin from span, and place span between buttons? https://jsfiddle.net/gx8knx7j/

Answer (score 1):

I used the `:after` pseudo for this. If you specifically wanted a '|' instead of a border you can use `content`.

```css
.footer-button1{
     background-color: #85b59d;
           width: 60px;
           margin-top: 10px;
           display: inline-block;
           text-align: center;
           height: 30px;
           border-radius: 5px;
           border: none;
           margin-bottom: 10px;
           position: relative;
           margin-right: 13px;
      }
 
 .footer-button1:first-child:after {
  display: none;
 }
 
.footer-button1:after {
  width: 1px;
  height: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: -10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
         <button type="button" class="btn footer-button1">Update</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn footer-button1">Delete</button>
                    </div>
```